# if internet explorer resize printing page to 60%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

i'm stuck with my work when printing in IE

when i'm using chrome or mozilla everything works fine
this is a screenshot of my page:

[image]

but when when i use IE everything is not working like it should work :(

this is screenshot from IE:

[image]

This is my code:

```
    <?php
include("bd.php");

$print[] = null;

if(isset($_GET['option1'])) {
    $print = $_GET['option1'];
}

$integerIDs = array_map('intval', explode(',', $print));
$usersIDS = implode(',', $integerIDs);
$requete = "SELECT p.pr_id as id, p.pr_nom as nom, p.pr_poids as poids, p.pr_ingredients as ingredients, p.pr_description as description, p.pr_valeurs_energetiques as valeurs_energetiques, p.pr_valeurs_nutritionnelles as valeurs_nutritionnelles, c.ca_nom as categorie, sc.sc_nom as sous_categorie, p.pr_enligne as enligne FROM produit p,categorie c,sous_categorie sc WHERE p.pr_id_categorie=c.ca_id AND p.pr_id_sous_categorie=sc.sc_id AND p.pr_id IN ({$usersIDS})  ORDER BY pr_ordre";

$resultat = mysql_query($requete);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($resultat);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="fr">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            font-size: small;
        }
        .lewa {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="window.print()">
<!--<body>-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!--right-->
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <?php
            if($num_rows > 0) {
            /*
          Start with variables to help with row creation;
        */
            $startRow = true;
            $postCounter = 0;

            $idCheck = 0;

            while($num_rows > 0){

            $ligne = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultat);

            if ($startRow) {
                echo '<div class="row">';
                echo "<img class='logoPuricard' src='./images/logo.jpg' >";
                echo '<div class="col-sm-12">';
                echo "<!--    TEST 6 kolumn        -->";
                echo "<div class='row'>";
                $startRow = false;
            }
            $postCounter += 1;
            ?>
            <?php
            $id = $ligne["id"];
            $nom = $ligne["nom"];
            $poids = $ligne["poids"];
            $ingredients = $ligne['ingredients'];
            $description = $ligne['description'];
            $valeurs_energetiques = $ligne['valeurs_energetiques'];
            $valeurs_nutritionnelles = $ligne['valeurs_nutritionnelles'];
            ?>



            <div class="col-sm-3" style="width: 32%" >
                <?php if (file_exists('../Assets/produit_'.$id . ".png")) {?>
                    <img src="../Assets/produit_<?php echo $id; ?>.png" style="width: 8em; float: left" />
                <?php  } ?>
                <?php echo "<p style='font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold;'> " . $nom . "</p><br>
                       <b>Poids</b>"
                    . $poids . "
                        <br><br><br>" . $description
                    ."<!-- DIV Ingrédients START -->
                        <div style='border: solid 2px #000000;padding: 1.5em;min-width:285px'>
                        <b style='text-decoration: underline;'>Ingrédients :</b>
                            <br><br> ".  wordwrap($ingredients, 30, "\n", false)
                    . "</div>  <!-- DIV Ingrédients END -->
                        <div></div>
                        <br>
                        <!-- DIV Valeurs énergétiques START -->
                          <div style='border: solid 2px #000000;padding: 0.5em;min-width:285px'>
                         <br><b style='text-decoration: underline;'>Valeurs énergétiques :</b><br><br>" . $valeurs_energetiques
                    . "</div>
                         <!-- DIV Valeurs énergétiques END -->
                         <br>"
                ?>
                <!-- Valeurs nutritionnelles START -->
                <div style='border: solid 2px #000000;padding: 0em;min-width:285px;'>
                    <b style='text-decoration: underline;'><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;Valeurs nutritionnelles :</b><br><br>
                    <div class='tableNutritionneles'>
                        <?php echo $valeurs_nutritionnelles;  ?>

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            var el = document.getElementsByClassName('tableNutritionneles');
                            window.addEventListener('load', function () {

                                var td = document.getElementsByClassName("tableNutritionneles");
                                var nrOfCollumns = td.length;
                                for(var i = 0; i < nrOfCollumns; i++){
                                    var styles = td[i].getElementsByTagName("table")[0].style;
                                    styles.minWidth = "100%";
                                    styles.maxWidth = "100%";
                                    styles.overflow = "hidden";
                                    styles.textAlign = "center";

                                }

                            });

                        </script>

                        <!--  Valeurs nutritionnelles END -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Allergènes START -->
                <!-- DIV Allergenes start -->
                <div style='border: solid 2px #000000;padding: 1.5em;min-width:285px;margin-top: 10px;'>
                    <br><p><b style='text-decoration: underline;'>Allergènes :</b></p>
                    <!--Table alegene start   -->
                    <style>
                        .logoPuricard {
                            margin-left: 44%;
                            width: 12%;
                            margin-top: 20px;
                            margin-bottom: 20px;
                        }
                        td {
                            border-collapse: collapse;
                            border: 1px solid #000000;
                            /*text-align: center;*/
                            /*vertical-align: middle;*/

                        }
                        .rotate {
                            font-size: 12px;
                            /* FF3.5+ */
                            -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
                            /* Opera 10.5 */
                            -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
                            /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
                            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
                            /* IE6,IE7 */
                            filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);
                            /* IE8 */
                            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";
                            /* Standard */
                            transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
                        }
                        td.alergenneTd {
                            opacity: 0.6 !important;
                            color: #FFEBCD !important;

                        }
                        .allergenePresent {


                        }
                        /*p:nth-of-type(6).*/
                        .allergeneTextCell {
                            margin-left: -41px;
                        }
                        @media print {
                            [class*="col-sm-3"] {
                                float: left;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:first-child{
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #33CC33 !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(2){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #3399FF !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(3){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #FFCCCC !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(4){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #003300 !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(5){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #3399FF !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(6){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #FF6B24 !important;
                                font-size: 8px !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(7){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #492544 !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(8){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #0080C0 !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(9){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #ABABD6 !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(10){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #FF8040 !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(11){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #000093 !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(12){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #007D00 !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(13){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #C0C0C0 !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(14){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #FFB366 !important;
                            }
                            body table td.alergenneTd:nth-child(15){
                                -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
                                background-color: #FF0CCC !important;
                            }
                            /*#allergeneTable {*/
                            /*padding-bottom: 10cm;*/
                            /*}*/
                            .tableNutritionneles  {
                                overflow: hidden;
                            }
                            .row {
                                margin-top: 1cm;
                                margin-bottom: 6cm;
                            }
                            .tableNutritionneles {
                                margin: 0 auto;
                            }
                            .allergenePresent {
                                color: red !important;
                                font-size: 15px;
                                font-weight: bold;

                            }
                            /*.alergenneTd:first-child {*/
                            /*background-color: #0f0f0f;*/
                            /*}*/
                            .alergenneTdColors {

                                border: solid #000000 1px;
                            }
                            .logoPuricard {
                                margin-left: 44%;
                                width: 12%;
                                margin-top: 2px;
                                margin-bottom: 10px;
                            }
                            .pRed {
                                color: red !important;
                                font-weight: bold;
                            }
                        }
                        @page {
                            size: A3;
                            margin-left: -5cm;
                            margin-right: -5cm;

                        }

                    </style>



                    <table id="allergeneTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                        <?php

                        $colors = array("#33CC33","#3399FF","#FFCCCC","#003300","#3399FF","#FF6B24","#492544","#0080C0","#ABABD6","#FF8040","#000093","#007D00","#C0C0C0","#FFB366","#FF0CCC");
                        $presenceTab = array();
                        $tracesTab = array();

                        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
                        $allergenes = "SELECT a.al_nom as nom,pa.pa_presence as presence,pa.pa_traces as traces FROM allergene a,produit p,produit_allergene pa WHERE pa.pa_id_produit=p.pr_id AND pa.pa_id_allergene=a.al_id and p.pr_id=".$id." ORDER BY a.al_id ASC";
                        $resultat_all = mysql_query($allergenes);


                        $colorNumber = 0;

                        echo '<tr>';

                        while($ligne_all = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultat_all))
                        {
                            $colorNumber++;

                            $nom = htmlentities(stripslashes($ligne_all["nom"]));
                            $presence = $ligne_all["presence"];
                            $traces = $ligne_all["traces"];

                            /*fill $presenceTab and $tracesTab with results*/
                            $presenceTab[$colorNumber] = $presence;
                            $tracesTab[$colorNumber] = $traces;

                            $fruit = "Fruits à coques";

                            ?>


                            <td class="alergenneTd"  style="background-color: <?php echo $colors[$colorNumber];?>;border: 1px solid #000000; color: #000000" >
                                <?php
                                if($colors[$colorNumber] !== "#492544"){?>
                                    <div class='rotate'><p class='allergeneTextCell' style='padding-top: 53px;color: #ffffff;'><?php $nomAll = html_entity_decode($nom); echo $nomAll;?> </p></div>
                                <?php }elseif($colors[$colorNumber] == "#492544"){?>
                                    <div class='rotate'><p class='allergeneTextCell' style='padding-top: 53px;color: #ffffff;font-size: 8px'><?php $nomAll = html_entity_decode($nom); echo $nomAll;?> </p></div>
                                <?php } ?>



                            </td>

                        <?php
                        }
                        echo "</tr>";
                        ?>
                        <?php
                        //                        echo "<tr>";
                        for($i=0; $i<$colorNumber; $i++){
                            if($presenceTab[$i]=="y")
                            {
                                ?>
                                <td style="padding-left: 4px;" >
                                    <span><font class="pRed" style="color: red; font-weight: bold;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle">P</font></span>
                                </td>
                            <?php
                            }
                            else if($tracesTab[$i]=="y")
                            {
                                ?>
                                <td style="padding-left: 6px;padding-top: 6px">
                                    *
                                </td>
                            <?php
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ?>
                                <td class="trace_allergene">
                                </td>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            <!--                        </tr>-->
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        <!-- DIV Allergenes end -->
                </div>
                </table>
                <script>
                    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                        var rotates = document.getElementsByClassName('rotate');

                        for (var i = 0; i < rotates.length; i++) {
                            rotates[i].style.height = 117 + 'px';
                            rotates[i].style.width = 17 + 'px';

                        }

                        var tds = document.getElementsByClassName('alergenneTd');

                    });

                </script>
                <!--Table alegene end   -->
                <p><span class="allergenePresent">P</span>: Présence</p>
                <p>* : Présence possible</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php

        if ( 3 === $postCounter ) {
            echo ' </div>'; /*END OF ?????*/
            echo '</div><!-- END OF INTERNAL ROW -->';
            $startRow = true;
            $postCounter = 0;
        }

        --$num_rows;
        }/*endWhile*/

        if ($postCounter !== 0 ) {
            echo '</div>';
        }

        }else {
            echo '<div class="page-header"><h1>Pas des resultat</h1></div>';
            echo ' <p>desole vous n\'avez pas choisir des produits</p>';
        }

        if ( 3 === $postCounter || $num_rows == 0 ) {
            echo '</div><!-- END OF INTERNAL ROW -->';
            $startRow = true;
            $postCounter = 0;
        }
        ?>


        </body>
</html>
```

is there any possibility to resize page to 60%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possibilities.

- First you can change the page setup of your internet explorer
  browser, go to **Tools -> Print -> Page setup**. Here you can Enable
  **Shrink-to-Fit**.
- Another way is to convert your webpage to a PDF-file. And then the
  PDF-file of your page can be printed.

**EDIT**
To put one chocolate on one page, use the CSS code below in the chocolate class:

```
page-break-after:always
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but even after using yours advice i get the same result in IE like in sceenshot...  i would like but i cannot use pdf files

Comment: when i trying to print just one item on a page and second item i would like to print on another page how to skip from page 1 to page 2 ?  do you have some advice please

Comment: Allright, lets test something. Open this webpage in IE then go to **Tools --> Print --> Print preview** and tell me what you see. The full page, or just half the page?

Comment: I do not understand your second question. you want **Anne Lait** on one page, **Brazil** on another page?

Comment: first sorry for my bad english, when you want to print 3 items each on one page, how to do it...yes i would like to have Anne Lait on one page, Brazil on another page

Comment: like <br> for break line, i would like something like <BREAK-PAGE> :)

Comment: Oke, well you are printing a HTML page, So you print what you see. So if you want to put each item on a separate page, you must change your HTML file. Put your items under eachother instead of next to each other with HTML and CSS.

In your CSS, use `display: block;` for each chocolate

Comment: "Reptar" i'm getting the same result like in 2 screenshot when doing preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83741/discussion-between-reptar-and-user3648216).

Comment: i have created a page with many checkboxes where you can choose amount of products that you want to print. Some description of product are longer and taking more space than others. So when i'm choosing all products after X pages printing is bad and braking in the middle this is my situation, so after each line with 3 products i would like to put some <BREAK PAGE>